# How to run Apple Mail on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, apple-mail

Is there a way (e.g. emulator or any other technology) to allow Apple Mail to work perfectly on Windows 7 64?

Comment: what're you actually trying to do? You could, practically either use an OS X system for apple mail, or use a regular mail client

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because I like the Apple Mail program most. But I'm not interested in working in Apple OS.

Answer (score 2):

[Psystar provided unauthorized OS X computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psystar_Corporation) for a time but they were eventually shut down by Apple.  OS X is contractually limited to run on Apple hardware.  This means that OS X applications must run on OS X which must run on Macs.  There is another project in development called [Darling](http://www.itworld.com/open-source/367440/run-os-x-apps-linux-darling) but that does not seek to run OS X apps on Windows but rather to run them on Linux.

Edit: Darling side-steps the OS X operating system requirement by translating OS X system infrastructure to Linux infrastructure.  This means that you don't actually have to use OS X "under" the application and therefore the requirement to run OS X on Mac hardware is also side-stepped.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in OS X with VMWare Workstation or VirtualBox (although it's AFAIK is against Apple's license), otherwise no, there's no such kind of an emulator to just run Apple Mail without an OS X itself.

Comment: that would consume a lot of resources or no? VMWare has that Fusion option which perhaps would work, cause the Mail program would appear as a regular windows application.

Comment: @FernandoSBS it would take about 4 GB of RAM to run OS X and a bit of CPU load (10-30%).

Comment: @FernandoSBS if you really like/need Apple Mail that much, you can always consider running OSX86 or getting a Mac, a lot of end-user software has its ports and alternatives on OS X. There's also wine and software to run virtual machines so you can use Windows apps in OS X with less resources used.

Comment: I like Windows Live Mail, the problem is I don't like the new versions and I absolutely hate ribbon interface. I have never found a viable replacement for WLM. Apple Mail seems to be a good option.

Comment: @FernandoSBS how about Outlook 2010 or Mozilla Thunderbird instead?

Comment: I'm not very sure if I have tried outlook in specific 2010 version, but I did try one of the outlook's. Problem is: let's say I start using Outlook 2010... I will come to the same problem as Windows Live Mail... must keep using the same version for ages because the new one add's something I find unacceptable, like the ribbon interface. I also have tried Thunderbird but for some reason I didn't want to keep with it over WLM.

Comment: Just an opinion, the ribbon interface is the best thing ever. Before everything was neatly categorized and organized into **ONE** ribbon, things were all over the place with so many toolbars, each new version of *Office* adding new toolbars and menus. If you had enabled all the toolbars in *Word* 2003, it would fill up more than half the screen! The ribbon simplified all that by categorizing the features into logical categories and subcategories, and prioritizing the ordering by usage and importance. **It is one of the things that Microsoft did right.** Don't hate the ribbon - give it a chance